# while loop and getchar()

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have the simple program below that I wrote for a college course. I know it doesn't really do anything, but it's just an assignment for a course.

The part that I can't figure out, is why doesn't the outer loop work?

The user needs to press '1' to continue, and any other key the program exits.

However, it still doesn't continue if the user presses '1' and instead exits anyway.

I tried adding a cin.clear() before cin >> repeat, but that doesn't work.

I also tried playing around with cin.ignore(), but that didn't seem to help either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
int main()
{
    int repeat = '1';
    stack<char> cstr;
    char c;

    while (repeat == '1')
    {
        cout << "Enter in a name: ";

        while (cin.get(c) && c != '\n')
        {
            cstr.push(c);
        }

        cout << "\n Enter another name? 1 = Continue, any other key to exit the program";
        cin >> repeat;
        repeat = getchar();
   }
}
```

Comment: why are you assigning a string to an integer repeat?

Comment: @reggie that's not a string, it's a char.

Comment: What are you expecting to be in `repeat` after the line `cin >> repeat;`?  And **then** what would be in it after `repeat = getchar()`?

Comment: @reggie I originally had repeat as an int but changed it along the way somewhere when trying to solve my looping problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing at all wrong with your code. It seems to be working fine for me.

EDIT: Sorry it doesn't work until you remove the getchar. Forgot to mention that. Simple way of finding out the error is to just display the value of the variable repeat to see what the value is and where it is going wrong.

Screenshot to show you that your codes work

[image: Screenshot of your working codes]

Everything seems to be working fine. I would like to comment on your program structure though. For small programs like this it's ok but always best to practice the logical way. For questions like this you should implement the do while loop instead of the while loop so that it goes in without checking and then accepts the user input and checks with the post condition. Example below.

```
    char  repeat;

    do
    {
        //Your codes in here
    }while (repeat == '1');
```

It is more logical to use this method instead unless your question specifies you to use while loop. Anyhow hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
   cin >> repeat;
```

it reads repeat as int. (1 is not equal '1')

```
repeat = getchar();
```

It reads int code of special char '\n' - symbol end of line.

You must use

```
char repeat = '1';
```

Or write

```
int repeat = 1;
```

and not use getchar()

Answer (score 1):

Run this . it will solve your problem somehow repeat=getchar was making repeat=10.

```
 int main()
    {
    char  repeat = '1';
    stack<char> cstr;
    char c;

    while (repeat == '1')
    {
        cout << "Enter in a name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        while (cin.get(c) && c != '\n')
        {
            cstr.push(c);
        }

        cout << "\nEnter another name ? \nPress 1 to Continue : ";
        cin >> repeat;
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: have you run this code. it works as u wished. 
1st problem was outer loop not working then other was that it was not taking input.

Answer (score 1):

The line `cin >> repeat` is tring to read an integer from the keyboard because `repeat` is a variable of type `int`. However, you are verifying if the integer read from the keyboard is equal to 49 (the ASCII code for the character '1'), which is not what you want. A solution would be to replace the line

```
int repeat = '1';
```

with

```
int repeat = 1;
```

and also replace

```
while (repeat == '1')
```

with

```
while (repeat == 1)
```

because then you are comparing the integer read from the keyboard with the integer 1 (rather than the *character* '1'). Also, at the end of the loop you read input from the keyboard and store it in `repeat` but then you immediately read input again and *store that value* in `repeat`, replacing its previous value. To solve this, replace the line

```
repeat = getchar();
```

with

```
getchar();
```

and that should do it.